# The purpose of escaping html entities

Tags: html, encoding, data-validation

By security principles, we are often taught to sanitize input fields for characters such as `&` or `'` so that they cannot be used for SQL injections etc.

However, now I have an issue: I really need to store a string input which would contain these characters. It is a business requirement. My code scanners would definitely flag this into a warning alert as this is classic SQL injection vulnerability if I do not sanitize the input. My database would then store the string `&amp` instead of `&` (just an example). But this is not what we wanted. We really wanted the literal `&` or `'` stored in database.

What are the good ways to go about doing this?

Comment: Use a prepared statement?  SQL injection is only an issue where you naively insert the parameters into a query using string concatenation.  Here's owasp's guide for defending against SQLi attacks: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Ideally you would escape special characters only when necessary (i.e. when you convert them into HTML)

Comment: @immibis The problem is that **it  is almost always necessarily** to escape special characters

Comment: @begueradj The way you sanitize user data is dependent on the context of where it is being used (example: HTML vs HTML Attribute vs PDF export). You shouldn't be sanitizing user input before storing it because you may want to output it in a different manner in the future (like in this case). Also parameterised queries is the way to prevent SQL injection, not replacing & or ' in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any decent static analysis scanner would not flag up a vulnerability if you were storing raw HTML in your database - after all, it's only a string.

String sequences only become dangerous when passed through a "sink function".

For example, `<script>` is completely safe to store in your database. In fact so is 
[`Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--`](https://xkcd.com/327/).

The latter is only dangerous when it is passed from a string variable and concatenated to a hard coded query in the application because the whole string is passed to the database server and it does not know the difference between the query and the data. This is why you should use parameterised queries to pass data to your database - then the DB itself knows what to interpret as strongly typed data, and what to interpret as the query construct itself.

When outputting to the browser, this is where you need to encode as appropriate. Usually you will be outputting to HTML, so you need to HTML encode (`&` becomes `&amp;` as you say). If you're outputting to JSON or JavaScript (don't though it's a minefield) then you should output the text with hex entity encoding instead (`\x38`).

Comment: **In opposite**, any decent scanner **must** flag the presence of HTML entities in the database because there are more nefarious reasons for its presence than innocuous ones especially when your application is hosted on the Internet.

Comment: I disagree. It's just text to the database. An example is Stackexchange.com -  think about all the html from code snippets stored in there. A scanner flagging this is what causes such confusion with developers. The focus on prevention of XSS should be primarily on output encoding, although input validation can be done as a secondary measure (eg name field should only contain alphas, dashes and apostrophe) .

Comment: I saw websites using PHP-Markdown library or similar tools to render HTML input into text to be able to store it in the DB, but it is a risk for a website to store HTML. Also, input sanitization is important especially if you develop in something like PHP.

Comment: @begueradj - What the risk with storing HTML in a database? I completely disagree that a scanner must flag this. If there is an XSS risk, that occurs when the HTML is read from the database and returned to the user - and only if done insecurely; there are safe ways to do it (e.g. escaping).

Comment: @paj28 Can you weight the number of nefarious and innocuous possibilities of HTML characters to be landed into the DB? Especially when your application is exposed on Internet. The good practice is to sanitize the inputs, a second security layer is to check the presence of such characters in the DB because you can not be sure that you have sanitized all your inputs when your application is of a huge scale. The presence in itself may and may not be dangerous, but think about the causes of its presence in the DB: it will be too confusing for security analysis and thus risky

Comment: @begueradj - glad you have accepted that "presence in itself may not be dangerous". That idea that "input validation is best practice" is a very basic concept taught to security beginners. If you build or audit large applications you realise that output sanitisation is a better model. This is because sanitisation depends on the context (HTML, SQL, LDAP...) and you only know the context when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid storing such characters for reasons you mentioned (and others), that is the best for you. However  if you are forced to regarding your business model you still have an option: Whatever the programming language you are using,  you can always rely on the concept of [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) to fulfill that goal. That way you [prevent  SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29).

Comment: For the benefit of the OP, it's probably worth clarifying the distinction between escaping to prevent SQL injection and that done to prevent other forms of attack (such as malicious JS injection). The former is done when storing data - parameterized queries being probably the simplest and best means - and the latter when preparing data for display. The two should not be confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to persist those characters, ensure that you used bind variables (or prepared statements) to persist them.

You should also then add HTML Encoding when displaying the information on your User Interface.